# Avoiding nested each loops when handling nested JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object:

```
{
   "custom_sql_rule":[
      {
         "custom_sql":[
            "Should start with a Select",
            "Should not contain ;",
            "Some other error"
         ],
         "something_else":[
            "Error",
            "Should not contain ;",
            "Some other error"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "someother_rule":[
      {
         "sdfsdf":[
            "Should start with a Select",
            "Should not contain ;",
            "Some other error"
         ],
         "sdfsdf":[
            "Error",
            "Should not contain ;",
            "Some other error"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to append each string error to a div. I quickly whipped this up:

```
var errorMessages = function(errors, errorsContainer) {
  $.each(errors, function(index, value) {
    $.each(value, function(i, v) {
      $.each(v, function(ia, va) {
        $.each(va, function(iab, vab) {
          errorsContainer.append($("<div></div>").addClass(index).text(vab));
        })
      })
    })
  });
};
```

It's terrible. Is there a nicer way of handling JSON formed like this? NOTE, I cannot really use keynames.

Comment: Don't use `each`, use regular for loops??? You have deeply nested data, you'll need a deeply nested loop, or you can use the suggestion from http://stackoverflow.com/a/16930041/227299, that is use recursion looking fore something that is an array of strings, but that sounds much worse than the nested loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that will iterate over a tree of objects and arrays, identifying each string.

```
function eachLeafString(dataObject, callbackMethod) {
    if(typeof dataObject == 'string') {
        callbackMethod(dataObject);
    }
    else if (Object.prototype.toString.call( dataObject ) === '[object Array]') {
        $.each(dataObject, function(index, elem) { eachLeafString(elem, callbackMethod); });
    }
    else {
        for(var propertyName in dataObject) {
            eachLeafString(dataObject[propertyName], callbackMethod);
        }
    }
}
```

For an example of this working: http://jsfiddle.net/e6XN7/3/

If you want to use the index of the first-level nodes, you could use it as follows:

```
  $.each(errors, function(index, value) {
    eachLeafString(value, function(vab) {
         errorsContainer.append($("<div></div>").addClass(index).text(vab));
    });
  });
```

Comment: Mhh that fine, but you dont take care of the "addClass(index)"... All of your error div are not stylized with the proper css.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is "just" javascript object literals.  You can skip the jQuery call, and just reference the objects and arrays directly after you `parse` it.

```
obj.custom_sql_rule[0].something_else[0];
```

of course, your JSON is a bit oddly-formed.  If at all possible, don't arbitrarily mix objects `{}` and arrays `[]` . Use the latter when you have lists of identical objects or primitive data, and the former when you have named properties.  And once you have a valid javascript object, you can just iterate through its properties.

```
for(var sqlProp in jsonObj) {
  if(jsonObj[sqlProp].error) {
    errorsContainer.append("<div>" + jsonObj[sqlProp].error + "</div>");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a recursion function like this :

```
function errorMessages(errors,errorsContainer,errorclass)
{

  if ( typeof errors == "string")
    errorsContainer.append($("<div></div>").addClass(errorclass).text(errors));
  else
  {
    $.each(errors, function(classname, value)
          {

           errorMessages(value,errorsContainer,(typeof errorclass == "undefined") ? classname : errorclass );                           
      });
   }
};
```

Check it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aa3Ea/1/)

When you call your function, dont pass the third argument, he will be  null so your class will be get from your JSON. If you pass a class in thir param, it will overide the one in your JSON. You choose :)

But you can modify and optimise it for sure...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying your code that runs through the JSON, you can modify the structure of the JSON itself and make it "wider/flatter" instead of "deeper".

```
//errors

[
  {
    "error" : "custom_sql_error",
    "subcategory" : "custom_sql",
    "messages" : [
      "Should start with a Select",
      "Should not contain ;",
      "Some other error"
    ]
  },
  {
    "error" : "custom_sql_error",
    "subcategory" : "something_else",
    "messages" : [
      "Error",
      "Should not contain ;",
      "Some other error"
    ]
  },
  {
    "error" : "someother_rule",
    "subcategory" : "sdfsdf",
    "messages" : [
      "Should start with a Select",
      "Should not contain ;",
      "Some other error"
    ]
  },
  {
    "error" : "someother_rule",
    "subcategory" : "sdfsdf",
    "messages" : [
      "Error",
      "Should not contain ;",
      "Some other error"
    ]
  }
]
```

That way, you loop through like this

```
$.each(errors, function(index, value) {
  $.each(value.messages, function (index, message){
    $("<div/>").addClass(index).text(message).appendTo(errorsContainer);
  });
});
```